# How do I create a .txt file at a location in terminal without changing the current directory?

Tags: command-line

I need to create a .txt file at a specific location without changing the current directory with the `cd` command.

For example, I need to navigate to /username/Desktop with `cd`, and I need to create a .txt file in /username/Documents/folder

Answer (score 1):

The `touch` command will create a blank new file at the path you specify.

If you want to create `example.txt` in your user's Documents folder, you would use the following command:

```
touch ~/Documents/example.txt
```

-or-

```
touch /home/username/Documents/example.txt
```

Please be aware that you must specify a valid path that already exists. The example you used in your question is not a valid path, so it won't work.

Comment: Other than a valid path, the user must have "write permission" to the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a one-line command

```
cd ~/Desktop ; gedit ~/Documents/Personal/afile.txt
```

and you'll see a visual WYSIWYG text editor. A Save button on the upper right corner will help you retain whatever you typed.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nmath emphasized, you could give the full path to the `touch` command and create a  new file on the existing directory. You could use TAB after typing several letters of the path to see all the possibilities in the directory branch you are on. Another alternative is to use a relative path. E.g:

Check your current working directory:

```
$ pwd
/home/user/folder1/folder2
```

Then, create file using relative path:

```
$ touch ../../Documents/new.txt
```

To check if the file is created use `ls` and `grep` commands:

```
$ ls ../../Documents | grep new.txt
new.txt
```

if you get the result below the ls command you are ready to go.

Comment: It is inadvisable to parse the output of `ls` as the results may be unreliable. In this case the `grep` seems exceptionally unnecessary as one can simply `ls /path/to/file`. Also, an example using a relative path may be useful here, but why use a relative path in your scenario when the absolute path `~/Documents/new.txt` is shorter?

Comment: I agree that the relative path might be longer sometimes. However, my point on using a relative path is to be able to navigate without prior knowledge of the file system tree. That being said, parsing the `ls` output also serves a purpose here. It's easier to find the exact file if the target directory contains a lot of folders and files. And direct `path/to/file` works as well. Just grep serves my choice of taste here.